# Performance of double np.einsum and how to speed up

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-einsum

Consider this [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=[14,25,25])
b = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=[14,25,25])
c = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=[14,25])

def my_func(a,b,c):
    InnerSum = np.einsum('lpk, lkm -> lpm', a, b)
    OuterSum = np.einsum('lp, lpm -> lm', c, InnerSum )
    Result = 2 * OuterSum
    return Result
```

my_func() was my first attempt to do the calculation but I wanted to speed it up. I then tried it with the following modified function:

```
def my_func_2(a,b,c):    
    OuterSum = np.einsum('lpk, lkm, lp -> lm', a, b, c)
    Result = 2 * OuterSum
    return Result
```

However, when I run `%timeit` on both functions, I get

```
%timeit my_func(a,b,c)
293 µs ± 1.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit my_func_2(a,b,c)
347 µs ± 1.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Why is the second approach slower than the first? How can I optimize my_func() to make it faster?

Comment: Try with `optimize` set as `True` : `np.einsum('lpk, lkm, lp -> lm', a, b, c, optimize=True)`?

Comment: On my laptop `my_func_2` is about x10 faster. Anyway, have a look at this project to understand what `optimize=True` does in `np.einsum`: https://github.com/dgasmith/opt_einsum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the loop count (the length of `a` and `b`)  isn't a huge number as compared to the lengths along the other axes, we can run a simple loop and leverage BLAS supported matrix-multiplication at each iteration. The lengths also mean enough sum-reductions per iteration, justifying a for-loop for such a case.

The implementation would be -

```
N,M = b.shape[::2]
out = np.empty((N,M))
for i in range(N):
    out[i] = c[i].dot(a[i]).dot(b[i])
out *= 2
```

#### Benchmarking

Using the `optimize` argument, which seems to boost up the performance of `my_func_2` appreciably and also adding in the proposed one as another function -

```
def my_func(a,b,c, optimize=False):
    InnerSum = np.einsum('lpk, lkm -> lpm', a, b,optimize=optimize)
    OuterSum = np.einsum('lp, lpm -> lm', c, InnerSum, optimize=optimize)
    Result = 2 * OuterSum
    return Result

def my_func_2(a,b,c, optimize=False):    
    OuterSum = np.einsum('lpk, lkm, lp -> lm', a, b, c,optimize=optimize)
    Result = 2 * OuterSum
    return Result

def my_func_3(a,b,c):
    N,M = b.shape[::2]
    out = np.empty((N,M))
    for i in range(N):
        out[i] = c[i].dot(a[i]).dot(b[i])
    out *= 2
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [51]: # Setup used in the question
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=[14,25,25])
    ...: b = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=[14,25,25])
    ...: c = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=[14,25])

# With einsum optimize set as False
In [52]: %timeit my_func(a,b,c, optimize=False)
    ...: %timeit my_func_2(a,b,c, optimize=False)
    ...: %timeit my_func_3(a,b,c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 255 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 302 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.7 µs per loop

# With einsum optimize set as True
In [53]: %timeit my_func(a,b,c, optimize=True)
    ...: %timeit my_func_2(a,b,c, optimize=True)
    ...: %timeit my_func_3(a,b,c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 334 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.6 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: `optimize=True` will DGEMM; however, it's not smart enough to build out a loop GEMM like in your `func_3`. `my_func` with `optimize=True` just builds out additional overhead on the order of ~100us as shown.

Comment: @Daniel What exactly do you mean by being not smart enough with func_3? Agreed on my_func part.

Comment: `optimize=True` can only handle the choice between `tensordot` and the canonical `einsum`. The optimal solution here is to introduce a python-based for loop which `optimize=True` will not cover.

Comment: @Daniel Don't think a loopy one with `optimize=True` would do any better than loopy-dot based one, if that's what you are implying.

Comment: No, it won't unless the shapes make the `(a*b)*c` vs `a*(b*c)` a significantly better contraction one way or another. Just trying to point out why `optimize=True` is more expensive in `my_func` while less expensive in `my_func2`.